# Web Browser Redirect won't open activity, despite intent-filter in manifest

Tags: android, oauth-2.0

I have following code in manifest :

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

        <data android:host="www.myreddittest.com"/>
        <data android:path="/r2"/>
        <data android:scheme="https"/>
        <data android:pathPattern=".*"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

Login button onclick :

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(LOGIN_URL));
startActivity(i);
```

**Scenario** :
When I click the login button, the browser is opened and a website's authorization page is loaded (Reddit in this case).
After clicking "allow" on that page the browser is redirected to

```
 https://www.myreddittest.com/r2
```

but the activity will not be opened (instead the browser tries to reach the url and fails).

**Problem :**
my app works on one of my phones and on the emulator. But my primary phone won't open the activity after the redirect.

**Question :**
Could this be a bug in that phone's OS ? What can / should I do to make sure it works on **all** phones ?

Any suggestions to prevent this behavior are deeply appreciated !

Comment: I'm not an Android developer, but have you tried posting on reddit about it? You might find help on /r/redditdev or /r/androiddev.

Comment: actually I have, but r/androiddev says I should post it on stackoverflow. Nevertheless I think my problem has more to do with Android, and is not Reddit specific.

Comment: It may help if you generalize your problem -- see if you can recreate the problem in a non-reddit specific app, and find where it overlaps.

Comment: You're right, it's not Reddit dependent. I removed the tag and simplified the post.

Comment: Are you using the same browser within the devices? Also, try debugging the device or looking in logcat to see the response that is coming back.  I know you need to make sure that everything matches exactly. For example, does it pass back as http instead of https or myreddittest.com/r2 instead of www.myreddittest.com/r2? I have used this app to test my deeplinks and it was very useful debugging an issue. This app can point you in the right direction as to where the problem is. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.manoj.dlt

Comment: I tested it with the app, it worked ! So it sometimes works, and sometimes not. However, I changed my approach, I had to code more lines but now my app opens a new activity instead of simply asking the system to handle the Url. My new activity has a WebView. That gives me the option to interrupt the redirects and if the redirected Url is the one I'm looking for I handle the response and close the activity (with the WebView). That way users won't encounter any errors due to the state of their device/system. Thanks for the link, this app might come handy when debugging link in future !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a new activity instead of asking the system to handle my Url.
Instead of this :

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(LOGIN_URL));
startActivity(i);
```

I now have this code :

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(R2App.getContext(), R2AuthorizationActivity.class), 1234);
```

This activity consists of one WebView inside :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Some code of activity :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.layout_webview);

webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.loadUrl(LOGIN_URL);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        if (url.startsWith(LOGIN_REDIRECT_URI)) {
            view.stopLoading();

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(R2AuthorizationActivity.this);
            builder.setView(R.layout.layout_webview_overlay);
            builder.setPositiveButton("CANCEL", null);

            // CREATE ALERT DIALOG
            alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();

            doStuffWithParameterAndCallFinish(Uri.parse(url).getQueryParameter("code"));
        } else
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    });
}

void finish(boolean success) {
    alertDialog.cancel();
    setResult(success ? Activity.RESULT_OK : Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
    finish();
}
```

layout_webview_overlay.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/activityBackground"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/accent"
        android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:text="Authorizing ..."
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

</LinearLayout>
```